# Fastest way to combine an image and audio file to make a video using ffmpeg

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg, python, video-conversion

i am using ffmpeg to combine an image and audio to make video with this command from my python program

`process = subprocess.Popen('ffmpeg -loop 1 -i "{picture}" -i "{audio}" -c:v libx264 -tune stillimage -c:a aac -b:a 192k -pix_fmt yuv420p -shortest "{out_path}"'.format(picture=picture, audio=audio, out_path=out_path), stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=False)`

but it is taking very long almost 30-45 minutes on my pc with specifications 1GB Ram and intel xenon processor. is there any way to make this process faster i am ready to compromise the quality (decent).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -framerate 1 -i image.png -i audio.m4a -map 0 -map 1:a -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -tune stillimage -vf fps=10,format=yuv420p -c:a copy -shortest output.mp4
```

- Default frame rate for image input is 25. You can use a much lower input frame rate and a normal output frame rate. Duplicating frames is cheap, so it is faster.
- Use a faster [x264 encoding preset](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264#Preset).
- If the input audio format is compatible with the output format then [stream copy](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy) (`-c:a copy`) the audio instead of re-encoding it. Otherwise, use `-c:a aac` for MP4 output.
- If outputting MP4 consider adding the `-movflags +faststart` option. It can allow the video to begin playback faster for your viewer.

Comment: great it worked like charm, however i tweaked fps param to 1 instead of 10 and and even faster now. but can you explain why got even faster? and i didn't find any quality loss

Comment: @RitikSahuStudent Yes, encoding 1 fps should be faster than 10 fps. However, there is a minimum fps that most players can handle. 10 should be a safe number. You can experiment if you are targeting a specific player/device to see the lowest fps it will accept and properly decode.